# How to record iOS mobile screen for more than 600 seconds using appium?

Tags: ios, automation, appium, video-recording, screen-recording

Appium provides a default screen recoding time of 600 seconds for iPhones. I want to record the screen for 1000 seconds. How do I do it?

I am using start_recording_screen() to initiate screen recording and stop_recording_screen() to stop the recording.

I am using appium and python to automate my tests. Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'timeLimit' capability and set it to the desired screen recording time limit in seconds (in this case, 1000 seconds)

`'timeLimit': 1000`